# Looking for any matching terms from file

Tags: python

I have a file that has a large list of Countries, years, and ages of living expectancies. I cannot figure out how to make sure the user is only allowed to input a year that actually exists. After figuring this out, I will need to call only those years (with corresponding country name, code, and living expectancies. How can I do this?

```py
import pathlib

cwd = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
data_file = f'{cwd}/life-expectancy.csv'

with open(data_file) as f:
    while True:

        user_year = input('Enter the year of interest: ')
        
        for lines in f:
            cat = lines.strip().split(',')
            country = cat[0]
            code = cat[1]
            year = cat[2]
            age = cat[3]
        if any( [year in user_year for year in cat[2]] ):
            print(f'Your year is {user_year}. That is one of our known years.')
            print(year)
            print()
            continue
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid year (1751-2019)')
        
            
        print('test')
```

Comment: Couple of comments: You read your file in every user attempt. Why not read it once before you go to the input section? And please add an example of how the interaction of the user with the script should be, e.g. by showing what the console should look like in various cases.

Comment: Are all the dates from 1751 to 2019 present in your file?

Comment: What is the code and age from the 'life-expectancy.csv'? Could you provide an example value under this column?

Answer (score 0):

One could use **DataFrames** to handle such cases. To know more information on dataframe, take a look into [Pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

To select specific column contents from the dataframe: `df[[<col_1>, <col_2>]]`

Considering the data fetched could produce the following.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Life Expectancy Data.csv")

year = int(input("Enter the year of interest: "))


df = df[["Country", "Year", "Life expectancy "]]

if year in df["Year"].values:
    print(f'Your year is {year}. That is one of our known years.')
    display(df.loc[df["Year"] == year])
else:
    print("Please enter a valid year (2000-2015)")
```

Comment: @[Ethan N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14018457/ethan-n), were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

If all the dates from 1751 to 2019 are in your file, then you don't need to read your file to check that, you can simply do that:

```py
# Ask the user for the year
prompt_text = "Enter the year of interest: "
user_year = int(input(prompt_text))
while not 1751 <= user_year <= 2019:
    print("Please enter a valid year (1751-2019)")
    user_year = int(input(prompt_text))
```

After that you can read your file and store the data only if the years are matching:

```py
# Get the data for the asked year
# Example of final data: [("France", "FR", 45), ("Espagne", "ES", 29)]
data = []
with open(data_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        country, code, year, age = line.strip().split(",")
        if int(year) == user_year:
            data.append((country, code, int(age)))
```

## Solution 2

If you really need to check the year in your file, e.g. because 1845 is not in it, then read the file once and store all the data in a dictionary indexed by the year and return the data of the asked year if it is present:

```py
data = {}
with open(data_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        country, code, year, age = line.strip().split(",")
        year = int(year)
        if year in data:
            data[year].append((country, code, int(age)))
        else:
            data[year] = [(country, code, int(age))]

prompt_text = "Enter the year of interest: "
user_year = int(input(prompt_text))
while user_year not in data:
    print("The year is not present in the file")
    user_year = int(input(prompt_text))
print(data[user_year])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question includes two questions.

## 1. Question and answer

> I cannot figure out how to make sure the user is only allowed to
> input a year that actually exists.

Your range of accepted years is 1751-2019. You could create a list with these integers and check that the user input is within that range. E.g.

```
allowed_answers = list(range(1751, 2019, 1))
```

There are multiple ways to check the user input and the one you want to use depends on how you want the user interaction to be. **Here are few examples:**

**1.Stop the program immediately if user input is invalid**

```
user_year = input('Enter the year of interest: ')
allowed_answers = list(range(1751, 2019, 1))
assert user_year in allowed_answers, "User input is invalid"
...
```

**2.Ask user to input number until it is accepted**

```
allowed_answers = list(range(1751, 2019, 1))
user_year = 0

while int(user_year) not in allowed_answers:
   print('Please enter a valid year (1751-2019)')
   user_year = input('Enter the year of interest: ')
```

**3.Combining the two solutions to have a limit of prompts.**

```
allowed_answers = list(range(1751, 2019, 1))
user_year = 0

for i in range(0,5):
   print('Please enter a valid year (1751-2019)')
   user_year = input('Enter the year of interest: ')
   if int(user_year) in allowed_answers:
       input_valid = True       
       break
   else:
       input_valid = False

assert input_valid, "No correct input after five tries."
```

**Note that all these solutions only handle inputs that can be converted into integer.** To go around that, you might need some try... except clauses for the data transformation from string to integer, or transform the list items of allowed_answers into strings.

## 2. Question and answer

> After figuring this out, I will need to call only those years (with corresponding country name, code, and living expectancies. How can I do this?

I would read the file only once a make it into a dictionary. Then you only need to do the indexing once and search from there as long as your program is running. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries .

With these suggestions I would do the data reading and transformation into dictionary outside (and before) your while loop.